# Style attribute is getting removed from the img tag in outlook email

Tags: image, email, outlook, styles

Style attribute is getting removed from the `img` tag in outlook email.
Please find my code sample below.

```
<td valign="top" style="padding-right: 20px; width: 25%; text-align: center;">
    <img src="image.jpg" style="max-width: 310px; max-height: 200px;" alt="Hotel image">
</td>
```

Comment: <td valign="top" style="padding-right: 20px; width: 25%; text-align: center;">
<img src="image.jpg" style="max-width: 310px; max-height: 200px;" alt="Hotel image"></td>

Comment: Don't wait that Outlook will render HTML emails like a browser, it supports very limited set of tags and styles.

Comment: @UladzimirPalekh, Thanks for reply.. it's working fine  for other e mail clients.. Any Work around for Outlook that will be helpful.
Even its not accepting any class name for img tag.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments - *edit your question* instead.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook ignores the width and height from the style tag, if you are using retina images, the images will show at actual size. Use width and height on the image tag. It will solve your problem.

```
<td valign="top" style="padding-right: 20px; width: 25%; text-align: center;">
<img src="image.jpg" width="310" height="200" style="max-width: 310px; max-height: 200px;" alt="Hotel image">
```

Cheers